# realizar operaciones entre subdocumentos de mongoose desde nodejs

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose

tengo una consulta acerca de poder realizar opereciones como suma y resta entre subdocumentos almacenados en mongodb desde nodejs.
Tengo el siguiente modelo de base de datos y quiero que cada vez que valla agregando un nuevo subdocumento de abonos al documento de una persona se valla actualizando la variable de totalPagado dentro del subdocumento agregado, en el siguiente esquema no lo esta haciendo

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60304a8e9eecff3ab837cad3"
  },
  "name": "Marcos",
  "prestado": 600,
  "abonos": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "603083f24b438d6550797e1a"
      },
      "abono": 5
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "603087284b438d6550797e1d"
      },
      "abono": 20,
      "fechaAbono": "19/2/2021",
      "totalPagado": 20
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6030872d4b438d6550797e1e"
      },
      "abono": 30,
      "fechaAbono": "19/2/2021",
      "totalPagado": 30
    }
  ],
  "fecha": "19/2/2021",
  "interes": 30,
  "saldo": 330,
  "__v": 0
}
```

El siguiente codigo lo utilizo para agregar un nuevo subdocumento de abonos y desde aqui deberia poder ir actualizando la variable de total pagado ya sea sumando todos los abonos realizados o que cada vez que se agrege un pago esta variable se valla actualizando.

```
const updateAbono = (req, res = response) => {
  const deudorId = req.params._id;
  const abonado = req.body;

  const fecha = new Date();
  const dia = fecha.getDate();
  const mes = fecha.getMonth() + 1;
  const ano = fecha.getFullYear();

  Deudor.findByIdAndUpdate(
    deudorId,
    {
      $push: {
        abonos: {
          abono: abonado.abono,
          fechaAbono: dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano,
          totalPagado:abonado.abono
        },
      },
    },
    (error, sucess) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Error al actualizar el abono" });
      }
      if (!sucess) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "No existe el deudor" });
      }
      return res.status(200).json({ resp: sucess });
    }
  );
};
```

muchas gracias de antemano.

saludos.

Comment: El total abonado (o el monto adeudado)  es un valor que se calcula al momento de la consulta y no es una valor que se almacena en la DB. En la Base de datos sólo almacenarás el valor del préstamo, el interés aplicado a dicho pŕestamo, y los valores de los abonos y amortizaciones. Cada vez que hagas un abono, sólo almacenas el monto y fecha del mismo. El valor adeudado a la fecha de la consulta se calcula basándose en estos datos y de ninguna manera se almacena ese valor en la DB, porque puede generar discrepancias. Saludos

Comment: Oohh, entiendo amigo, muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda