# Duplicado a un metodo al usar async/await

Tags: nodejs, mongodb, express, mongoose, async-await

Buenas tardes comunidad

estoy realizando una inserción a un arreglo que se encuentra en la base de datos de mongodb, estoy utilizando el async/await para realizar esta consulta, pero a la hora de realizar la ejecución se me esta duplicando la inserción y me esta generando conflicto.

seria de gran ayuda la que me puedan dar, muchas gracias de antemano

```
const updateAbono = async (req, res = response) => {
  const deudorId = req.params._id;

  const resp = await Deudor.findByIdAndUpdate(
    deudorId,
    {
      $push: {
        abonos: {
          abono: req.body.abono,
        },
      },
    },
    (error, sucess) => {
      if (error)
        return res
          .status(500)
          .json({ message: "Error al actualizar el abono" });
      if (!sucess)
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "No existe el deudor" });
      return res.status(200).json({ sucess });
    }
  );

  const newSaldo =( resp.saldo - req.body.abono) + ((resp.saldo - req.body.abono) * 0.10);
  await Deudor.findByIdAndUpdate(deudorId, { saldo: newSaldo });
};
```

Comment: Estás mezclando `callbacks` con Promesas. Eso ya indica un problema. O usas `callback` o usas Promesas, pero no ambas. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

**PROBLEMA**

Según lo que veo en tu código estás haciendo 2 actualizaciones al mismo documento en una misma operación. Esto es algo que deberías evitar a toda costa, debido a que se pueden producir inconsistencia de datos al efectuarse una actualización si y la otra no.

Como vas a actualizar un mismo documento, puedes actualizar ambos campos a la vez, ya que todo proceso de actualización sobre documentos en MongoDB es una operación atómica, por lo tanto no existe posibilidad de inconsistencia de datos en una actualización de este tipo.

Por otro lado, te di un consejo en este [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/429725/realizar-operaciones-entre-subdocumentos-de-mongoose-desde-nodejs#comment767207_429725) en otra pregunta sobre un tema similar. Usualmente los saldos deudores no se almacenan en base de datos, los mismos se calculan al momento de realizar una consulta. Pero dado que estás empeñado en almacenar el *saldo* adeudado, puedes hacerlo justo al momento de actualizar un abono.

Además, uno de los problemas que tienes en tu código es que estás mezclando el uso de `callbacks` con Promesas. Específicamente en esta parte del código:

```js
const resp = await Deudor.findByIdAndUpdate(id, update, callback); // <- no uses await con callback.
```

El método [`findByIdAndUpdate()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) de Mongoose devuelve un objeto de tipo [`Query`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html), y lo que realmente tú deseas (o es lo que uno quisiera) es obtener una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Promise) para poder trabajar con [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/await), para que el método nos devuelva una Promesa debemos usar el método [`exec()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-exec) de dicho objeto `Query` devuelto.

Por último, cada vez que trabajamos con Promesas y la sentencia `await`, debemos capturar el posible rechazo de las mismas. Es por ello que debemos usar un bloque `try ... catch` para capturar correctamente la posible excepción ocurrida al fallar el código ejecutado en la Promesa (cuando la Promesa es rechazada).

**SOLUCIÓN**

Lo primero debemos hacer es calcular el nuevo saldo antes de hacer la actualización, ya que el mismo va atado al abono realizado por el deudor. Sin embargo, es aquí donde se presenta el mayor problema, la [atomicidad de la operación](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operaci%C3%B3n_at%C3%B3mica). Para poder calcular el nuevo saldo debo leer el saldo almacenado, restar el abono con su interés y almacenar el abono y el nuevo saldo. Parece simple, pero resulta que son 2 operaciones: leer el saldo previo y guardar el nuevo saldo calculado junto con el abono.

Si ocurre que durante el proceso entre las 2 operaciones otro cliente realiza una actualización del documento afectando el saldo que acabamos de leer, no tendremos forma de saberlo, dando como resultado que el saldo calculado será erróneo y esto introducirá una inconsistencia en los datos.

Es por ello que los saldos, por lo general, se calculan al momento de la consulta y no se persisten en la Base de Datos, a menos que se use un sistema de Transacciones, en las cuales se garantice que la operación a realizar sobre el documento sea una operación atómica.

Si dejamos de lado la posibilidad de que otro cliente haga una actualización en la base de datos, el problema se reduce a leer el saldo almacenado, calcular el nuevo saldo basándonos en el monto del abono y actualizar el documento. Esto lo podemos lograr con:

```js
const updateAbono = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let deudor = await Deudor.findById(deudorId, {saldo: 1}).exec(); // <- devuelve efectivamente una Promesa
    if(!deudor) {
      return res.status(404).json({
        message: `Deudor con id: ${deudorId} no existe.`
      });
    }
    
    let { saldo } = deudor;

    let newSaldo = (saldo - req.body.abono) + ((saldo - req.body.abono) * 0.10) // <- req.body.abono debe ser numérico 
    
    // Ahora ya podemos actualizar el documento en una misma operación
    let update = {
      $set: {
        saldo: newSaldo, // <- nuevo saldo
      },
      $push: {
        abonos: {
          abono: req.body.abono, // abono realizado
        },
      },
    };
    
    let updated = await Deudor.findByIdAndUpdate(deudorId, update, {new: true}).exec();
    return res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Actualización correcta',
      deudor: updated
    });
  }
  catch(e) {
    // Si ocurre cualquier error, será capturado por este bloque
    console.error(e.message);
    return res.status(500).json({
      message: 'Ocurrió un error en la operación',
      error: e.message
    });
  }
}
```

Esta sería una forma de realizar la operación de actualización de saldo y abono conociendo previamente el saldo deudor. Recuerda que esto no es una operación atómica, ya que entre el momento de la lectura del saldo anterior y la actualización con el nuevo saldo, el documento puede cambiar en la base de datos.